# Differential of a map including a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> Let $f\in C^{k}(M,\mathbb R)$ with $M$ is a $m$-Manifold and $d_xf:T_xM\to\mathbb R$ is the surjectiv differential. Let $m\lt l$ and $L:\mathbb R^l\to\mathbb R^{m-1}$ be a linear map and $G:M\to\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^{m-1}$ with $G(a)=(f(a),L(a))$. Furthermore is $A=ker(d_xf)\subset\mathbb R^l$ and $L$ is regular on A. Then $d_xG(u)=(d_xf(u),L(u))$.

Question: How do I get $d_xG$?

Comment: Should that be, "How do I get $d_x G$?"? The symbol $F$ appears to be undefined, but the derivative you've written down looks like the right one for $G$. If that IS the right question, the answer is this: apply the chain rule to the maps $Q(a) = (a, a)$ and $H(a, b) = f(a), L(b))$, since $G = H \circ Q$.

Comment: yes, you are right it is G! I edit it now. Ok I try it later. Then I will post it.

Comment: @JohnHughes So, i did it now: $d_xG(u)=d_x(H\circ Q)=d_{Q(x)}d_xQ=(d_xf(u),L(u)) (1,1)$, it is not the same result as above.

Comment: *$d_{Q(x)}Hd_xQ$